# Why would Angular be cutting off string?

Tags: angular

I have a custom component, that can have a version specified. The version number for the component is in the form of [major.minor.index] and is passed to the component as a input parameter with the name [version].

In the component, the parameter is set as a string, explicitly, to ensure that we don't loose the [.index] portion of the version number (this is intentional), however, when we display the number that comes from calling component, the [.index] portion of the version number is cut off:

- expecting '1.1.9'
- actual '1.1'

Am I missing something here? Don't see why Angular, on it's own, would do this?

```
// Calling component

<custom-component
    [version]="1.1.9">
</custom-component>

// Custom component

// omitted for brevity

  @Input() version: string = '1.1.8';

  private env = environment;

  constructor() {
  }

  get setVersion(): string {

    let version = this.version;

    if (!('yamlLocation' in this.env)) {
      version = '1.1.8'; // TODO: pull this from YAML file
    }

    return version;
  }

// omitted for brevity
```

Comment: I doubt this work. When you surround version with brackets `[version]` angular will be looking for an object (here it looks for var named : `1.1.9`). So you sould do `version="1.1.9"` or `[version]="'1.1.9'"`

Comment: @Florian yeah, wrapping 1.1.9 as a string reference, works, however, i don't understand why 1.1.9 would cut off the .9, it's like Angular believes the value being passed to the property, is a number. that's really the question i'm asking :$

Comment: Yes, angular is interpreting your value as a number here. He tries to interpret the object `1.1.9` which can't be a variable (obviously, no number in variable name), so he tries as a number and the result of `1.1.9` is `1.1`

Comment: Probably should be `<custom-component [version]="'1.1.9'"></custom-component>`

Answer (score 0):

After some reading regarding this issue it turns out that @Florian in his comment is correct.

Angular interprets a value containing a full-stop as a numeric value, if it's not wrapped in the string literal notation [version]="'1.1.9'", which is why [version]="1.1.9" resulted in the 1.1, as a numeric value cannot contain more than one full-stop.

The behavior is even stranger on different locale's, where numerals / decimals are represented by a comma (,).

To represent something similar to this in Angular, pass the string as a variable to the component, or use the string literal notation as a rule of thumb.